# "Idem" string in small caps with biblatex

Tags: biblatex, small-caps

I have used the command `\renewcommand{\mkibid}[1]{\emph{#1}}` to put the strings *op. cit.* and *ibid.* in italics.

However, the string *idem* (appearing when an author has been cited just before) is also in italics, and I want it in small caps.

Does anybody has an idea of how to do that?

*Edit: adding a minimal example*

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{french}

\usepackage[backend=biber,
            sorting=nyt,
            block=space, 
            hyperref = auto, 
            citestyle=verbose-trad2,
            bibstyle=verbose-trad3,
            citepages=omit  
            ]{biblatex}

\usepackage{csquotes}   

\renewcommand{\mkibid}[1]{\emph{#1}}
\addbibresource{Biblio.bib}

\begin{document}
First \footcites{bollman1998romische}{bollman1966cannophori}

And second\footcite{bollman1966cannophori}
\end{document}
```

gives

[image]

In the second note, I would like to change the format of the Idem from italics to small caps.

Comment: Why do you want inconsistent formatting? Regardless of why, please provide a minimal example i.e. code for a small document which we can compile to reproduce the issue. It may well be that there is no generic solution and that any answer will depend on the details of your usage of Biblatex, which we cannot guess.

Comment: We need a [minimal example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/8528) (or see [here](http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=minxampl)) for this because it really depends on what style you're using. I suspect you may need to do something like `\providecommand*{\mkidem}[1]{\textsc{#1}}` and then do something like `\renewbibmacro*{cite:ibid}{\printtext[bibhyperref]{\bibstring[\mkidem]{ibidem}}`.  But it may not be so simple. (@cfr -- in some German [e.g.] journals, it is common to put the author in small caps, including a `\textsc{id}.` or `\textsc{ea}.` when it is the same author.)

Comment: Thanks for your answers. I have edited to add the minimum example. As jon has written, in French historical journal, the author names must appear in small caps... and Idem as well

Comment: Almost there. For bibliography-related questions, the relevant `.bib` entries are often helpful as well.

Comment: But, for `citestyle=verbose-trad2`, you may be able to do use the above `\providecommand*{\mkidem}[1]{\textsc{#1}}` and then `\renewbibmacro*{cite:idem}{\bibstring[\mkidem]{idem\thefield{gender}}\setunit{\printdelim{nametitledelim}}}` (I just switched `\mkibid` to `\mkidem`).  But the multicite commands may also require surgery: they are tricky things.

Comment: Note that `citestyle=verbose-trad2,bibstyle=verbose-trad3,` is equivalent to the shorter `style=verbose-trad2` since both `verbose-trad2.bbx` and `verbose-trad3.bbx` just refer back to `authortitle.bbx`.

Comment: @jon : yes, it works perfect! Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The fix is easy in this case. You simply need to create an 'idem' macro and then substitute it in the `cite:idem` bibmacro:

```
\providecommand*{\mkidem}[1]{\textsc{#1}} 
% substitute: \mkidem for \mkibid
\renewbibmacro*{cite:idem}{\bibstring[\mkidem]{idem\thefield‌{gender}}\setunit{\p‌​rintdelim{nametitled‌​elim}}}
```

In passing, please also note **moewe**'s comment about how both `verbose-trad2.bbx` and `vrebose-trad3.bbx` simply load the `authortitle.bbx`. There is, therefore, no advantage to loading the 'verbose-trad2' citestyle and 'verbose-trad3' bibstyle.