# In biber idemgender not resolved when renewing macro cite:idem

Tags: biblatex, biber

With reference to [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/338828/idem-string-in-small-caps-with-biblatex) question, i found problems in renewing the macro `cite:idem` since the compiler can't resolve the variable  `idemgender`.

Here is an example derived from the cited question. The macro `cite:idem` is renewed to print its argument in small caps.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[italian]{babel}

\usepackage[backend=biber, citestyle=verbose-trad2]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}

@article{bollman1966cannophori, 
  author   = {Demidov, S.S.},
  title= {N.V. Bugaev e lo sviluppo della scuola matematica moscovita},
  journaltitle = {Ricerche di storia della matematica},
  date = {1985},
  number   = {XXIX},
  pages= {113-124},
}

@incollection{bollman1998romische, 
  author = {Demidov, S.S.},
  title= {N.V. Bougaiev et la creation de l'Ecole de Moscou},
  date = {1985},
  booktitle= {Mathemata.},
  editor   = {Folkerts, M.},
  publisher= {Steiner Verlag},
  location = {Stuttgart},
  pages = {651-673},
}

\end{filecontents*}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\providecommand*{\mkidem}[1]{\textsc{#1}} 
% substitute: \mkidem for \mkibid
\renewbibmacro*{cite:idem}{\bibstring[\mkidem]{idem\thefield‌{gender}}\setunit{\p‌​rintdelim{nametitled‌​elim}}}

\begin{document}
First \footcites{bollman1998romische}{bollman1966cannophori}

And second\footcite{bollman1966cannophori}
\end{document}
```

The output, compiled with LuaLateX, gives the following footnotes:

[image]

As you can see, instead of "Idem", the document prints the token **idemgender**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code in the question contains some invisible characters that mess things up. I have seen this effect several times on this site when code was copied from the comments.

Specifically there is a zero-width non-joiner (U+200c) between `\thefield` and `{gender}` as well as a zero-width non-joiner (U+200c) and a zero-width space (U+200b) after the `p` in `\printdelim` and and after the `d` in `nametitled‌​elim`. You can see that something is off with the `p` if you look at the code highlighting: All of `\printdelim` should be blue, but only the `\p` is blue in the code from the question.

A website like https://w3c.github.io/xml-entities/unicode-names.html can greatly help to find those pesky invisible characters.

When I remove the undesirable invisible characters the following works just fine

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage[backend=biber, citestyle=verbose-trad2]{biblatex}

\providecommand*{\mkidem}[1]{\textsc{#1}} 

\renewbibmacro*{cite:idem}{%
  \bibstring[\mkidem]{idem\thefield{gender}}%
  \setunit{\printdelim{nametitledelim}}}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{bollman1966cannophori, 
  author       = {Demidov, S.S.},
  title        = {N.V. Bugaev e lo sviluppo della scuola matematica moscovita},
  journaltitle = {Ricerche di storia della matematica},
  date         = {1985},
  number       = {XXIX},
  pages        = {113-124},
}
@incollection{bollman1998romische, 
  author    = {Demidov, S.S.},
  title     = {N.V. Bougaiev et la creation de l'Ecole de Moscou},
  date      = {1985},
  booktitle = {Mathemata},
  editor    = {Folkerts, M.},
  publisher = {Steiner Verlag},
  location  = {Stuttgart},
  pages     = {651-673},
}
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
First \footcites{bollman1998romische}{bollman1966cannophori}

And second\footcite{bollman1966cannophori}
\end{document}
```

[image: Idem, “N.V. Bugaev e lo sviluppo della scuola matematica moscovita”, cit.]